# Why doesn't it work code for changing date format from 'MM/DD/YYYY' to 'YYYYMMDD'?

Tags: python

I want to change date format from 'MM/DD/YYYY' to 'YYYYMMDD'.
But my code makes date format from 'MM/DD/YYYY' to 'MMYYYYDD'.

```
input_date = input("DATE(MM/DD/YYYY): ")

list_splited_date = input_date.split("/")
yy = list_splited_date.pop(2)
modified_date = yy.join(list_splited_date)

print(f"\"{input_date}\" -> \"{modified_date}\"")
```

Below is a execution result example.

```
DATE(MM/DD/YYYY): 04/16/2022
"04/16/2022" -> "04202216"
```

What's the problem??

Comment: Read the fine manual for what [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) does…? You just want `+`.

Comment: Or really… `from datetime import date` `date.strptime(input_date, '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%Y%m%d')`

Answer (score 1):

Using `yy.join(list_splited_date)` joins the elements in `list_splited_date` (which are `MM` and `DD`) by using the the separator `yy` (which is `YYYY`) between them, and not, as you might have thought, by simply concatenating `yy` with the contents of `list_splited_date`.

```
input_date = input("DATE(MM/DD/YYYY): ")
MM, DD, YYYY = input_date.split('/')
modified_date = f'{YYYY}/{MM}/{DD}'
print(f"\"{input_date}\" -> \"{modified_date}\"")
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
 yy.join(list_splited_date)
```

means to join the pieces with `yy` as a separator. In general it joins: `i0 sep i1 sep i2 sep i3 sep .... iN`.

In this case the list contains only MM, DD, so you get MM YYYY DD.

A simple code works fine:

```
split_date = input_date.split("/")
modified_date = split_date[2] + split_date[0] + split_date[1]
```